# WGET output to local drive us PHP system()

Tags: php, unix, wget

Is it possible to save the files retrieved by WGET to the "client side" using PHP system() function?

Test based on djechelon answer:

```
$targetfile = "C:\Work\test.css";

$url = "http://www.domain.com/temp/style.css";

$foo = system('wget $url > $targetfile');
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by local? Do you mean client side ?

Comment: Sorry, yes i mean client side.. @Viper_Sb can you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: @Stephen look at djechelon's answer

Comment: So your want your php page to modify a file on the client side ? The client that's viewing the website ?

Comment: Well this is a small question for a much larger problem i'm trying to solve. Basically, i need to generate a list of MP3's located a web server to be downloaded to the client side in a directory they specify.

Comment: Well using only php you can't do that ! Imagine a website that could read/modify all your files.... Of course if php is running on client side too then why not, but I suppose that you have a website that people are supposed to visit, haven't you ?

Comment: Right, that's what i always understood as well but I've been recently encouraged to research the possibility..thanks for the the help!

Comment: Don't know how encouraged you but he clearly does not understand anything about server/client side and php... You "could" try something using an applet java for example (some website provide online antivirus) but clearly not in php. Why don't you build a desktop application ??

Comment: Agreed. I basically had to prove this "theory" wrong before we could move on... you know how it goes. Actually, we are researching building a desktop application in Adobe Air. It's a new direction for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system('wget $url > $targetfile');
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this method now but i believe i'm doing something wrong... I'm appending the post with my current attempt.

Comment: @Stephen: try replacing `'` with `"`.

Comment: Ok, tried that. It's now copying the specified file, but outputting it to the directory of the script NOT on client side.

Comment: Oh, I believed you wanted to copy that onto server's "local" directory. Unfortunately, due to security restrictions, you can't arbitrarily copy a file to client's file system, but you might want to have the client download it into a user's specified folder, which is significantly different

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "local drive"? The client that's viewing the website that's displaying the contents of your PHP script?
If yes - then after downloading a file with wget you need to force the browser to re-download it from YOUR website to their computer. You can do this by saving the wget file into the public html directory and providing a link via php, or by sending a php command

`header('Location: '.$file);`

Good Luck!